# "I panicked" or "I was panicked"?

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, adjectives, passive-voice, past-participles

I want to refer to a situation that happened months ago. So what should I use? "I panicked" or "I was panicked"?

Answer (score 3):

*I panicked.* – past tense of verb 'panic' – compare 'I bottled it'.

*I was panicked.* – predicative (participial) adjective – compare 'I was afraid / scared'.

*I was panicked [by what happened].* – passive construction – compare 'I was kicked [by Bill]'.

Comment: I really don't understand why this answer has two negative votes.

Comment: It's not strictly an answer, Rahul, as it doesn't give an answer to '... which should I use?'. I chose to use the answer vehicle anyway as I felt the English involved was worth explaining and the 'comment' format would obscure the parallels. It answers the follow-on (and, I believe, intended) question 'Are both grammatically correct?', and shows the adjective-participle ambiguity also. You get used to people who put the letter of the law above the spirit.

Answer (score 0):

The verb "to panic" is transitive, therefore it can be used to indicate that something or someone panicked someone else.I would only use "was panicked" if your sentence contains the cause of the panic: "I was panicked by the storm.'

Comment: The passive usage is admittedly far more common than the participial adjective usage ( [panicked - AudioEnglish.org](http://www.audioenglish.org/dictionary/panicked.htm)
: Familiarity information: PANICKED used as an adjective is very rare.) However, 'I was panicked' is not incorrect. Compare 'We found that the window was broken' (broken: participial adjective) and 'The window was broken by the pigeon' (passive construction).

Answer (score 0):

As Edwin Ashworth and Matthew Haugen said, "I panicked" and "I was panicked" are both grammatically correct. Both are in the past tense.

As user84593 said, "I panicked" is probably a better choice in most contexts. Edwin Ashworth left a useful comment:

> The passive usage is admittedly far more common than the participial adjective usage ( [panicked - AudioEnglish.org](https://www.audioenglish.org/dictionary/panicked.htm) : *Familiarity information: **PANICKED** used as an adjective is very rare.*) However, 'I was panicked' is not incorrect. Compare 'We found that the window was broken' (broken: participial adjective) and 'The window was broken by the pigeon' (passive construction). – Edwin Ashworth

Grammatically, "I panicked" simply uses the intransitive verb "to panic" in the past-tense form.

"I was panicked" is more complicated to analyze. As Edwin Ashworth's answer indicates, in principle, it could be seen as either a standard "eventive/dynamic" passive construction, or as a "stative/static" construction where "panicked" can be analyzed as a predicate adjective. For a more detailed description of the differences between these types of constructions, see my answer on ELL to [*is “folded” a verb or adjective?*](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/117193/is-folded-a-verb-or-adjective/117220#117220)

In either case, it could be followed by a phrase starting with "by" that indicates the agent or instrument that caused the panic.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on what you mean. If you're talking about a specific occurence, the former ("I panicked") might be more appropriate. But if you're talking about something a bit longer-running, the other is better.

In other words, "I panicked" would be appropriate in a case like "I panicked when I ran into a spider web." On the other hand, you'd use "I was panicked" in a case like "I was panicked as the deadline approached."

But really, they're interchangeable in most cases. It's mostly just a matter of what sounds better.

Comment: So both are grammatically correct?

Comment: @ricky, yes. Both are grammatically correct. I like user84593's example that you should use "I was panicked" when you're indicating the cause, though. That's a good rule of thumb.

Comment: Shout-out to whomever voted this and @edwinashworth's answers down: please take a look at the reasons to vote an answer down in help. Specifically, "Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect." Voting answers down is an indication to users that they're dangerously incorrect, which neither of these is. Voting up is certainly acceptable--that person had a good answer--but voting down isn't appropriate here.

Answer (score -1):

No one is commonly used but *I panicked* sounds better.

Better options are *became panicky*, *felt panicked*, something *panicked me*, or do something *in a panic*.